# Problema Sincronizacion de Hilos

Tags: java, hilos

tengo un problema con la sincronizacion de hilos en java, os comento.

Estoy intentando hacer un programa tal que tengo un array de hilos y los ejecuto todos a la vez y cuya unica funcion es mover la posicion de un JLabel como si de una carrera se tratase, el problema es que tengo que lanzar todos los hilos y tengo que hacer que hasta que uno de ellos no haya dado un paso no se mueva el siguiente y asi es decir que si tengo 5 hilos pues el hilo 2 da un paso y hasta que este no termina de dar el paso no empieza el paso de otro y asi sucesivamente hasta que llega a meta pero no consigo que me funcione bien, os muestro el codigo:

> CLASE CONTROLADOR: ES CADA HILO QUE EJECUTO Y QUE CONTIENE MI ARRAY DE
>    HILOS EN LA CLASE VENTANA

```
public class Controlador extends Thread {

@Override
public void run() {
//Ficha es un JLabel que contiene la imagen del corredor
//Ventana es el JFrame sobre el que se encuentran los JLabel 
    int delay = generarNumeroAleatorio();

        while (!ventana.haLlegado(ficha)) {
        //ventana.haLlegado devuelve true o false si ha llegado al final de la pantalla
                ventana.movimientoSincronizado(this);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(delay);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                        ventana.mover(ficha); 
                    });


        }
    }
```

> CLASE VENTANA: CONTIENE LAS COMPONENTE Y EXTIENDE DE JFRAME

```
public class Ventana extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private boolean poderMoverse;
private Controlador[] hilos = new Controlador[8];


public void mover(JLabel ficha)
{
    ficha.setLocation(ficha.getX() + 50 , ficha.getY());
}
public synchronized boolean movimientoSincronizado(Controlador corredor)
{
    while (!poderMoverse) //Mientras no pueda moverse dejo el hilo en espera
    {
        try {
 //Cada hilo tiene como nombre la posicion que ocupa dentro del array
            int id = Integer.valueOf(corredor.getName());
            hilos[id].wait();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    poderMoverse = true; //Cambio el valor para que pueda moverse
    notifyAll();
    return poderMoverse;
}
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme, Muchas gracias a todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesante. Para este caso cree un JFrame(Carreras) para realizar la prueba funcional.

Este es el codigo autogenerado por Netbeans y dentro del constructor hice las modificaciones

```
public Carreras() {
    initComponents();

    // Este hilo es necesario para separar cualquier proceso del principal de la ventana grafica. Evita que se congele.
    Thread hiloBase = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // todos los caballos son jLabel
            iniciarCarrera(caballo1, 1);
            iniciarCarrera(caballo2, 3);
            iniciarCarrera(caballo3, 2);
            iniciarCarrera(caballo4, 4);
            iniciarCarrera(caballo5, 1);


        }
    });


    hiloBase.start();


}
```

Y este es el método que aplique para independizar cada carrera. Lo puedes colocar donde quieras (Para la prueba lo coloque antes del constructor como un método adicional)

```
public void iniciarCarrera(final JLabel caballo, int velocidad) {
    System.out.println("Iniciando carrera: " + caballo.getText());
    // Un hilo para cada elemento para independizarlos de los demas procesos e hilo base.  
    Thread carrera = new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("iniciado");
        int pasos = velocidad;
        while (pasos <= 100) {
            final int pasosdados = pasos;
            try {
                //cambios en el UI se deben hacer mediante el Event Dispatch Thread
                SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
                    caballo.setLocation(pasosdados, caballo.getY()); // desplazamiento del jlabel
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Carreras.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            pasos += velocidad;

            try { // solo para que se vea lento
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Carreras.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }, caballo.getText());
    carrera.start();
}
```

Por ultimo, si lo tuyo es aprender a desarrollar juegos te recomiendo GODOT 3.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he estado probando pero no es esto lo que necesito, mi idea es que, siguiendo el ejemplo que me has puesto, el caballo1 de 1 paso y todos los demas se esten quietos y hasta que ese caballo no ha terminado de dar el paso, no se mueve ningun otro. Cuando el caballo que tiene que dar el paso lo termina, los demas caballos (hilos) se pelean por ver quien da el siguiente paso y, hasta que este nuevo caballo no termine de dar ese paso, todos los demas han de estar quietos. Lo siento si no me he explicado correctamente

Comment: entonces tienes que tener una variable estatica que guarde el estado de lo que esta sucediendo. y con respecto a la idea de ver cual caballo arranca despues sugiero que uses random para dar un valor aleatorio y a partir de eso por ejemplo el valor mas grande es el que gana y hace que el caballo proximo inicie su carrera